# Container BoxShadow not working with InkWell Material

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to use Inkwell splash for this container.
Without Inkwell widget.

```
Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  blurRadius: 2.0)
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            color: _size.white,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.book,
                color: _size.green,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 4.0,
              ),
              Text('Instant'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

But when i add inkwell and material widget it looks like

```
Expanded(
        child: Material(
          color: _size.white,
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            onTap: () {},
            splashColor: Colors.red,
            splashFactory: InkSplash.splashFactory,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 2.0)
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                //color: _size.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.book,
                    color: _size.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Instant'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

I removed boxshadow from container and added elevation for material and i got like this.

```
Expanded(
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          elevation: 2.0,
          color: _size.white,
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            onTap: () {},
            splashColor: Colors.red,
            splashFactory: InkSplash.splashFactory,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                /*boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 2.0)
                ],*/
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                //color: _size.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.book,
                    color: _size.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Instant'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

finally it similar to what i need but in top of the container that coming shadow or elevation is not like needed one.
Anyone how to get shadow like first image.

Comment: Why don't you just use a raised button, which will already have the shadow and the onPressed callback with the ripple effect. You can shape the button and it;s children exactly like your existing container.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

I solved by wrapping Material widget by another Container widget and i give box shadow to this container, and i resolved my problem.

```
Expanded(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  blurRadius: 2.0)
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            color: _size.white,
          ),
          child: Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            color: _size.white,
            child: InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              onTap: () {},
              splashColor: Colors.red,
              splashFactory: InkSplash.splashFactory,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.book,
                      color: _size.green,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 4.0,
                    ),
                    Text('Instant'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using **`Card`**

```
Card(
            elevation: 10.0,
              child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.book,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4.0,
                ),
                Text('Instant'),
              ],
            ),
          ))
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Earlier i tried card also brother, when i use card top side shadow is not same as bottom side shadow. now i solved my problem brother. Thanks for your response brother.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ink` instead of `Material` when using `Inkwell`, then give the internal `Container` a color (it's transparent by default, just showing the shadow underneath):

```dart
Expanded(
  child: Ink(
    color: _size.white,
    child: InkWell(
      ...
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.white,
          ...
        ),
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I need ripple effect also, When i use Ink instead of Material, ripple effect not working. Now i solved my problem also. Thanks for your response.